# Принудительное перерендирование компонентов VUE

Tags: vue.js, dom, компоненты

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]Всем удачного кодинга к сути. Есть реализованная регистрация на сайте(написана на VUE 2). В регистрации есть 7 шагов(компонентов) которые открываются по мере заполнения текущего шага(данных в формах ввода текущей страницы). Например: заполнил первую страницу, открылась вторая и.т.д.

Проблема в том, что после внесения изменений не все изменения в компоненте обновляются на сайте. Простая очистка кеша не помогает. Приходится очищать регистр браузера(а посетитель сайте не будет при каждом посещения сайта очищать регистр своего браузера). Для примера самое простое с чем я столкнулся: если поменять тип input с text на date то это не будет обновлено. На сайте так же отображается input text. Хотя в коде уже input date написано.

Что я уже испробовал:

1. Написал для компонента условие если переменная равна true, то рендерься а если нет то соответственно нет. И при запуске по умолчанию переменная равно true, но вызывается метод и ставит false а после уже ставит true(хотел встряхнуть компонент).
2. Сделал для компонента :key и обновляю его после каждого своего изменения  и при обновлении страницы он разный для компонента(в надежде что компонент обновится увидев разное значение)

Ниче не помогло. Может у кого-то есть идея насчет этого?

```
   const registration = {
data: () => ({
    errorArray:{1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0,  5:0,  6:0, 7:0},                           
    step:1,                                                                     
    steps:{1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0,  5:0,  6:0, 7:0},
    pushData:{},
    token:"",
}),
created() {
    this.$root.$refs.bigcomponent = this;                                  
},
methods: {
    pushDataConvert(name,data){                                           
        this.$set(this.pushData, name, data);
    },
    valueAllComponent(i){                                             
        this.step=i;                                                 
        this.$root.$refs.headerNumberButton.addClassStep=i;         
    },
},
template: `<div>
                <page-name></page-name>
                <page-header-number></page-header-number>
                        <step1 v-if="step==1"></step1>
                        <step2 v-if="step==2"></step2>
                        <step3 v-if="step==3"></step3>
                        <step4 v-if="step==4"></step4>
                        <step5 v-if="step==5"></step5>
                        <step6 v-if="step==6"></step6>
                        <step7 v-if="step==7"></step7> 
                <page-footer-button></page-footer-button>
           </div>`,
```

};

Comment: На этом сайте присутствует великолепная функция вставки кода. Не используйте для этого вставку картинки, так вы только увеличиваете вероятность, что вам не ответят

Comment: Понял спасибо, исправил

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675549/how-do-i-cache-bust-imported-modules-in-es6
Мне понравился ответ с номером версии.

Comment: Да как вариант можно использовать. Просто с vue это как-то не удобно. С простым js файлом то можно было бы быстро. А тут множество компонентов. Поэтому искал более гуманный способ.